# Auto Update keeps turning itself back on

Tags: mac-appstore, auto-update

I'm running a Mac with Mojave and I don't want it to auto update. (Yes, I know I should let this go, but I have good reason not to.), anyway, It keeps turning itself back on randomly.

I have shut off automatic updates in System Preferences and in the App Store. But this setting keeps coming back on.

Comment: Recent Security update -> Apple Making It Harder to Avoid Nagging macOS Update Notifications: https://www.macrumors.com/2020/05/28/macos-ignore-software-updates/  Welcome to Apple's brave new world.

Comment: I have mine set to tell me & download but not auto-apply updates. that seems to work. Mine won't run Catalina, so at least I don't get that nag.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Thanks for that article. Unfortunately there is some software that just doesn't run on Catalina. I know this tactic likely save Apple the trouble of encapsulating code in their OS, but there are apps I still need. I'm disappointed with them. Does anyone know a file I can change to shut this off?

Comment: macOS will **never auto-upgrade**. only update within the current OS, so leaving it all switched on will only get you as far as 10.14.6 + the recent security update. You won't wake up one morning to find it's installed Catalina. That will categorically never happen. It may nag, but it won't do it itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin. Thanks. Im trying to make sure these setting just stay off and stop turning on, when they turn on again they reset other options the System Preferences.

Comment: Are you the only admin on the Mac? I've never known anything like that 'change its mind'. [but re my earlier comment, it won't hurt to have Mojave fully up to date.